# Line Break in HTML Breaks Styled Input on Safari

Tags: html, safari

**DO NOT TRY TO FORMAT THE CODE!!**

I have a styled input that for some reason is breaking if I put a line break in, as you can see in the example below. The code is exactly the same, except for there being a line break between the `<input>` tag and the `<span>` tag.

This is only occurring on Safari, and it becomes really problematic when I am using Cloudflare's Auto Minify HTML (took me hours trying to figure out what was wrong).

I am either looking for another way to add an icon to this input box or a fix for this.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<h2>Does not works:</h2>
<br>
<form class="chat-form mb-0">
<input type="text" placeholder="Message..." maxlength="255" enterkeyhint="send"
class="message bg-white border border-red-500 w-full pl-6 pr-12 py-3" />
<span class="absolute right-0 pr-3">
<button type="button" class="dictation pr-3 py-3 w-9 cursor-pointer">
<svg class="dictation-svg fill-gray-600 align-middle overflow-hidden" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path
d="M512 672c70.4 0 128-57.6 128-128V224c0-70.4-57.6-128-128-128s-128 57.6-128 128v320c0 70.4 57.6 128 128 128z" />
<path
d="M704 384c-15.4 0-28 12.6-28 28v138c0 90.4-73.6 164-164 164s-164-73.6-164-164v-138c0-15.4-12.6-28-28-28s-28 12.6-28 28v138c0 111.8 83.8 204.4 192 218.2V872h-72c-15.4 0-28 12.6-28 28s12.6 28 28 28h200c15.4 0 28-12.6 28-28s-12.6-28-28-28h-72v-103.8c108.2-13.8 192-106.4 192-218.2v-138c0-15.4-12.6-28-28-28z" />
</svg>
</button>
</span>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<h2>Works:</h2>
<br>
<form class="chat-form mb-0">
<input type="text" placeholder="Message..." maxlength="255" enterkeyhint="send"
class="message bg-white border border-red-500 w-full pl-6 pr-12 py-3" /><span class="absolute right-0 pr-3">
<button type="button" class="dictation pr-3 py-3 w-9 cursor-pointer">
<svg class="dictation-svg fill-gray-600 align-middle overflow-hidden" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path
d="M512 672c70.4 0 128-57.6 128-128V224c0-70.4-57.6-128-128-128s-128 57.6-128 128v320c0 70.4 57.6 128 128 128z" />
<path
d="M704 384c-15.4 0-28 12.6-28 28v138c0 90.4-73.6 164-164 164s-164-73.6-164-164v-138c0-15.4-12.6-28-28-28s-28 12.6-28 28v138c0 111.8 83.8 204.4 192 218.2V872h-72c-15.4 0-28 12.6-28 28s12.6 28 28 28h200c15.4 0 28-12.6 28-28s-12.6-28-28-28h-72v-103.8c108.2-13.8 192-106.4 192-218.2v-138c0-15.4-12.6-28-28-28z" />
</svg>
</button>
</span>
</form>
<br>
<br>


<br>
<br>
```